# GetWindowTextLength returns 0 when text is in the edit control

Tags: c++, winapi, utf-8

I'm writing a text editor and am having some issues with saving files as utf-8.
I have a function that reads text from a rich edit control and writes it to a file
using a flag passed to the function which depends on a user setting. It can be utf-16, ascii, or utf-8. Both utf-16 and ascii file writing segments *work fine* and produce valid files.
The problem lies in that in the following block of code the call to GetWindowTextLength always returns 0. So, the result is that nothing ever gets retrieved from the window or written to the file.

```
 HANDLE hFile;
 if ((hFile = CreateFile (pstrFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 
      NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      return FALSE;
 }

 int    iLength = 0;
 DWORD  dwBytesWritten = 0;

 switch (encoding) {

/*other text encoding cases*/

     case ID_SETTINGS_UTF_8: {
        try {
            iLength = GetWindowTextLength(hwndEdit);  //returns 0

            unique_ptr<wchar_t> wide_buf(new wchar_t[iLength + 1]);
            GetWindowTextW(hwndEdit, wide_buf.get(), iLength + 1);

            int bytes_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_COMPOSITECHECK |
                WC_DEFAULTCHAR | WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, wide_buf.get(), -1,
                NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

            unique_ptr<char> utf8_buf(new char[bytes_needed]);

            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_COMPOSITECHECK |
                WC_DEFAULTCHAR | WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, wide_buf.get(), -1,
                utf8_buf.get(), bytes_needed, NULL, NULL);

            WriteFile(hFile, utf8_buf.get(), bytes_needed, 
                        &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

            if (bytes_needed != dwBytesWritten) {
                        CloseHandle (hFile);
                         return FALSE;
            }

             CloseHandle (hFile) ;
             return TRUE;
        } catch (bad_alloc& ba) {
            UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ba);
            CloseHandle (hFile);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: You really have a design issue here. The call to `GetWindowTextLength` really shouldn't be unique to the UTF-8 code. You should get the UTF-16 text from the window in the common part. Similarly, the `WriteFile` call and its error handling should be in common code, too - nothing UTF-8 about that either.

Comment: A couple of troubleshooting questions: in the case where `GetWindowTextLength()` returns 0, if you pass a buffer with a reasonable size to `GetWindowText()` does it return anything?  Does `GetLastError()` say anything interesting (maybe call `SetLastError(0)` before to try to prevent reading a stale error code)?

Comment: Check the hwnd of the rich text edit in question, make sure it's a proper hwnd at the point that GetWindowTextLength is called on it

Answer (score 1):

You corrupt the heap. `new[]` must be matched by `delete[]`, not `delete`.

It's simpler to just use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> wide_buf(iLength + 1);
//...
std::vectorchar> utf8_buf(bytes_needed);
```

Comment: I see what your saying about delete now, after reading more carefully about unique_ptr. This is solved by changing the type specification to be unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>. But the call to GetWindowTextLength still returns 0 when the encoding is flagged as utf-8.

Comment: I seem to recall that MSVC6 was tolerant of such abuse of delete

Answer (score 0):

Is Your application compiled as UNICODE or ANSI ? (you use GetWindowTextLength and GetWindowTextW declarations)

Can you show code for ANSI and for UTF-16 (where you get proper result).